# I2C Disabled using Lightning Provider (DMMD) in Windows 10 IoT / Raspberry Pi 2

Tags: windowsiot, windows-iot-core-10

I just started looking into the [**Lightning provider**](https://github.com/ms-iot/lightning) and the first thing I tried by **I2C** and I found an issue. The I2C device (returned by `DeviceInformation`) shows it as **DISABLED** but when using the **Inbox Driver** shows as **ENABLED**.

I have a RBPi2 B with Windows 10 IoT 10.0.14393.67

I enabled DMMD Driver and created a simple program that makes reference to:

- Microsoft.IoT.Lightning: 1.1.0
- Microsoft.IoT.SDKFromArduino: 1.1.1

Also enabled the extensions:

- Windows Desktop Extensions for the UWP: 10.0.14393.0
- Windows IoT Extensions for the UWP: 10.0.14393.0

Modified Package.aspxmanifest with

```xml
<Package
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10"
  xmlns:mp="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/2014/phone/manifest"
  xmlns:uap="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/uap/windows10"
  xmlns:iot="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/iot/windows10"
  IgnorableNamespaces="uap mp iot">
....
  <Capabilities>
    <Capability Name="internetClient" />
    <iot:Capability Name="lowLevelDevices" />
    <DeviceCapability Name="109b86ad-f53d-4b76-aa5f-821e2ddf2141"/>
  </Capabilities>
</Package>
```

And with the following code:

```c#
public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();

    if (LightningProvider.IsLightningEnabled)
    {
        LowLevelDevicesController.DefaultProvider = LightningProvider.GetAggregateProvider();
    }

    CreateAsync();
}

private async Task CreateAsync()
{
    var aqs = I2cDevice.GetDeviceSelector("I2C1");

    var i2cDevices = await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(aqs);
    var i2cDevices_ManualAQS = await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync("System.Devices.InterfaceClassGuid:=\"{a11ee3c6-8421-4202-a3e7-b91ff90188e4}\" AND System.DeviceInterface.Spb.ControllerFriendlyName:=\"I2C1\"");
    var allDevices = await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync();


    foreach (var device in allDevices)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"{device.Id}  - {device.Name}");
    }
}
```

`i2cDevices` does not return any devices, but `i2cDevices_ManualAQS` returns 1 which is DISABLED (I manually changed the AQS to include enabled and disabled devices) and the `allDevices` shows there is a I2C1 device in it (`\\?\ACPI#MSFT8000#1#{a11ee3c6-8421-4202-a3e7-b91ff90188e4}\I2C1`)

If I changed the driver to **Inbox Driver** `i2cDevices` has 1 device and it is ENABLED.

So, either `DeviceInformation` is returning incorrect data or the I2C device is not enable with using Lightning.

I have already posted this message to the ["issues"](https://github.com/ms-iot/lightning/issues/43) section for that repo, but posted here too just in case I was doing it wrong and it was not a bug.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: I had the same issue with RP3, IoT 10.0.14393.0.